# Django redirects to login page even after logging in (I have used custom login login form)

Tags: django

code in views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login as auth_login

def login_view(request):

if request.method=="POST":
    login_form = LoginForm(request.POST)

    if login_form.is_valid():
        data = login_form.cleaned_data
        password = data["password"]
        username = data["username"]
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            auth_login(request, user)
            return redirect(reverse("account:profile", args=(user.id,)))

        else:
            validation_error = "Enter a valid email or password"
            return render(request, "account/login.html", {"form": login_form, "error": validation_error})

else:
    login_form = LoginForm()

return render(request, "account/login.html", {"form": login_form, "error": ""})
```

login.html template:

```
{% block login %}
{% if error %}
    <p style="color:red;">{{error}}</p>
{% endif %}

<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}

    <input type="submit" value="Log In">

</form>
{% endblock login %}
```

url.py:

```
url(r'login/', user_view.login_view, name='login'),
```

On going to "/" I'm redirected to "/accounts/login" which take me to the login page. After I enter the username and password, it takes me to the user profile page.

So far so good. Now Instead of being redirected to "/", I'm being redirected to "/accounts/login" again and am being shown the login page  again. Why?

Comment: post your `urls.py` and make sure that you successfully logged in

Comment: @PankajSharma, what do you mean by post your urls.py ?

Comment: show your urls.py file and maybe your template

Comment: Martins, posted login.html and url.py

Comment: @PradeepMishra need to understand where `reverse("account:profile", args=(user.id,))` making reverse call so post your `url_patterns`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,
    `return redirect('account:profile', user.pk)`

or if you want to check if the user is active or suspended etc,

```
if user is not None:
     if user.is_active:
        login(request, user)  # in your case auth_login as you are importing as auth_login
        return redirect('account:profile', user.pk)
```

Note: 
1. Make sure your profile url is correct i.e. `profile/<int:pk>/`
2. (not related to your question) - You can use Django's in built messages in place of validation error

Comment: Bidhan Majhi, I have already did this. I think the problem is in my model. I have created a Profile class and make inbuilt user one-to-one field and then added "is_active" and "is_admin" field manually:


    `class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)`